# Old Disney cartoon featuring cavepeople

Tags: story-identification, cartoon, disney

I saw this a real long time ago- I'd say early-mid 80's though I suspect the cartoon itself was much older. An anthropomorphic duck dressed up like a scientist (complete with nerd glasses) was narrating over animated shorts one of which revolved around cavepeople (though they were depicted as human). In the short, a caveman tries to woo a cavewoman with modern, non-violent ways (flowers, gifts, serenading her, that sort of thing) but she keeps acting like he doesn't even exist until out of frustration he bonks her on the head with his club and drags her home.

Comment: https://youtu.be/yLffxwRlXcc 1961 An adventure in color has a scientist and caveman duck but no ladies.  It's a very common trope though so it's likely elsewhere.  I seem to recall droopy dog doing it too

Comment: @lucasbachmann I am surprised that the rapey caveman scene you and the OP describe (which is *so* familiar) isn't listed on TV Tropes (at least not under the various caveman, and club tropes I just searched to link to).

Comment: There character would likely be [Ludwig Von Drake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ludwig_Von_Drake)

Comment: Ludwig did narrate the censored version of [Reason and Emotion](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nvp3zAPraF4), which features a caveman, but no scene of him wooing a cavewoman.

Comment: [The censored Ludwig version](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q3ZoSxTKQPE) although it looks like the picture cuts out about 10 minutes in, probably due to some copyright bit.

Comment: Daffy duck caveman cartoon but no romance https://youtu.be/L7CI-CHYavY

Answer (score 5):

I suspect you are looking for *[The Hunting Instinct](https://disney.fandom.com/wiki/The_Hunting_Instinct)*, which aired in 1961 on *Walt Disney's Wonderful World of Color* and was resampled for *Man's Hunting Instinct* in 1982 for *Walt Disney* (same anthology show, just periodically renamed for new seasons).

> Ludwig Von Drake hosts this episode, since Walt feels this noted expert on everything can shed some light on the subject of why man hunts. Von Drake has brought his assistant Herman the Bootle Beetle to help demonstrate the finer points of hunting.

### The Hunting Instinct

Searching for `disney ludwig cavemen` led me to [this forum topic](https://dvdizzy.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=3172&start=40) (bolding mine).

> The Hunting Instinct (10/22/61) Walt Disney introduces Ludwig Von Drake, who presents a program about man's hunting instinct.
>
> Note: Ludwig narration replaces part or all of original narration in the cartoons.
>
> Cartoons: (1) Bootle Beetle [1947] (2) The Pointer [1939] (3) Clown Of The Jungle [1947] (4) The Lone Chipmunks [1954] (5) The Plastics Inventor [1944] (6) The Fox Hunt [1938] (7) No Hunting [1955].
>
> TV animation created: (1) Animated Ludwig with live action Walt. (2) Ludwig introduces man's hunting instinct. (3) **Donald Duck as caveman who clubs a female for a mate; Donald as various scientists**. (4) Ludwig introduces his bootle bug friend Herman - leads into Bootle Beetle. (5) Herman fixes broken film - leads into The Pointer. (6) Ludwig introduces another hunter...the sponsor...who hunts for customers - leads into a commercial break. (7) Ludwig struggles with a camera and shoots off a gun to awaken his audience. Herman is shown with a live action projector - leads into Clown Of The Jungle. (8) Ludwig lectures on hunting for criminals - leads into The Lone Chipmunks. (9) Ludwig sings with the ending of the cartoon and falls off his chair - leads into a commercial break. (10) Ludwig plays with a yo-yo as he says "is the commercial over yet?" He uses a live action projector to show "The Von Drake Plastic Hour" - leads into The Plastics Inventor. (11) Ludwig blows a hunting horn and Herman starts a live action projector - leads into The Fox Hunt. (12) A framed picture of Donald Duck holding the skunk from the end of The Fox Hunt pans to a framed picture of Donald's hunting ancestor - leads into No Hunting. (13) Herman dives into live action projector to escape Ludwig's carelessly pointed gun. Ludwig is careless with a rifle - it goes off and the recoil throws Ludwig into a stuffed alligator.

Comment: No, I don't think this is it.

Comment: @Nu'Daq i suspect you a crossing memories of Walt Disney and this Tex Avery cartoon.   Consider how unlikely it is to get another cartoon duck with caveman than Fuzzyboots' answer.  And this i certainly saw as a kid too when i alluded to Droopy dog (not in this).  All humans and all concussions and hair pulling...   https://youtu.be/428sJRHES3Y

Comment: @lucasbachmann- Nope, the cavepeople didn't speak, no cowboy hats and the show I saw it on was called the (either wonderful or magical) world of Disney, that much I remember.